# Deploying resources from external projects in STS

Tags: java, eclipse, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I have a web app that I am deploying to Tomcat 7.0 using Eclipse STS.
My web project has some of its own xml config files, but apparently it pulls in or uses some external xml files from another java app in the work space.

The web app has config files in App>src>main>resources>config>spring>wiring.
The other project has xml files in a similar location that apparently the app requires in order to run. Is there a way in STS to get the xml resources from the external java project to deploy along with my web applications xml files? I feel like I have tried everything so far with no luck. My first thought is to use the Deployment Assembly, but this hasn't worked yet.

This app deploys and runs ok on a co-workers machine, but so far I have been unable to get it working.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Project Properties, Java Build Path, under tab Source there is a 'Link Source' button. It allows you to treat folders external to the project as containing source and resources.

This is one of my regular ways to switch configuration files between environments.